# How to download file with form submit using GEB

Tags: groovy, submit, geb

I'm building up a test in Geb (WebDriver) and need to *submit a form which will create a file in response*.

I am able to download the file (the Browser save it automatically to the disk), but I wand to check it in **GEB**.

- I've tried withNewWindow(), but it only works on URIs??
- I've tried downloadXXX(), but no luck either...

**How can I download a file into a variable?**

```
class CSVTest extends GebReportingTest 
    @Test
    void csvCreation() {
        to CSVExport

        // select entries / fill values
        selectAllEntries.value(true)

        //// this will do a post
        //// the server will render a file and deliver it back as a result of the submit
        // CORRECTLY downloads the file
        submitButton.click()

        // NOT WORKING
        withNewWindow (submitButton.click()) {
            ...
        }

        // NOT WORKING
        def csv = download(submitButton.click())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for asking the question. Let's see if someone comes to rescue us!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to intercept the file downloaded by the browser after clicking a button that does a post in any way unfortunately.

You will have to synthesize a post request with the right content which is sent when using the form. While it is possible to do so using Geb's [`DownloadSupport`](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/api/geb/download/DownloadSupport.html) class it will be complicated and clunky. You're better off using a library for which performing such requests is the main functionality, like for example [REST-Assured](https://code.google.com/p/rest-assured/).